# Wondering why I am getting duplicate arrays, with the same values. I need to arrange the string values together and integers separately?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Make it so it organizes strings differently from number types. i.e. [1, "2", "3", 2] should return [[1,2], ["2", "3"]]

```js
const stringArray = [1, "2", "3", 2];

function checkArrayString(arr){
    let emptyArray = [];
    let emptyArray2 = [];
    let emptyArray3 = [];

    for(let j=0; j<arr.length; j++){
        if(arr[j]===`${arr[j]}`){                 //looping to find string values in array
            console.log("working");
            emptyArray.push(arr[j]);                
            emptyArray3.push(emptyArray);
        } else{
            console.log("see five working");
            emptyArray2.push(arr[j]);     
            emptyArray3.push(emptyArray2);
            }
    }
    return emptyArray3;
}
```

Comment: `emptyArray3.push(emptyArray)` doesn't make a copy of the array.

Comment: Why not create the desired output array after the for loop? `return [emptyArray, emptyArray2];` Currently emptyArray3 is getting pushed to once every iteration of the loop, but seems like you always want exactly two elements in that array.

Comment: @Barmar what do you mean?

Comment: @CoryCoolguy what if there isnt exactly two elements in that array?

Comment: Well, you got strings and ints, that would be 2. You could check if the arrays are empty I suppose, but I still think you want it after the for loop.

Comment: @CoryCoolguy thank you so much